# c# Methods -non event based method will not add controls to form. Yet event based methods will. Why?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new at c# so here I go.

**This is what I originally thought was happening:**

I've a method (in php I called them functions) that creates a datatable and a DataGridView programatically, binds them, and then adds the DataGridView as a new control to a splitcontainer panel.

The thing is, if I use a button to execute this method it works, yet if I treat the method like a non-event based  function then the  DataGridView control will not add.

Changing the method code from this

```
private void f_rebuild_jobs_datagrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
```

to this

```
private void f_rebuild_jobs_datagrid()
{
```

prevents the controls from being added.

**This is what I believe is truly causing the problem:**

It should be mentioned that I can setup MessageBox alerts and they fire even when we use the ladder, so work is being done but the DataGridView control will not add... neither will other type of control (buttons, labels, etc).

Any advice on my mistake?

It might should be mentioned that when I am not using the button, I'm having a method on form2 fire the main datagridview generation function on form one. Basically I've a form that opens up and promts the user to change some information and then after closing the form the DataGridView should update and reflect changes.

The way I call the DataGridView generation function from form2 is :

```
   this.Close();
   form1 form1 = new form1();
   form1.f_rebuild_jobs_datagrid();
```

**This was my Solution.**

While I still am not sure why the function cannot add controls if executed from a separate form, I did find a solution to my problem by using .ShowDialog, rather than .Show to popup my dialog. This allowed me to execute a function, naturally, after the dialog closes. (Source: http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/379038-detecting-whether-form-has-been-closed-not)

Comment: Is this a web project or a windows project ?

Comment: Hey Nikshep, It's a windows project. I'm working in Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly of whats going on because you are not showing what the f_rebuild_jobs_datagrid() method does. But my assumption is that the line form1 form1 = new form1() creates a new form1 and runs that method. What you really wanted to be doing was open form2 by using this call:

```
form2.Show(this);
```

Then instead of creating a new form1 you can call your method from form2 like this:

```
((form1)owner).f_rebuild_jobs_datagrid();
```